# javascript fetch is fired double

Tags: javascript, django, fetch-api

I have a simple function in javascript that fetch and URL and update the HTML page when it got a response like:

```
 function post_db(self) {
   // other code here
   async function postData() {
      const url = "fetchnewseq"
      
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(comandi_json)
      });
      return await response.json()
    }
    
    postData().then((data) => { 
        window.location.replace(data.url); 
    });
   }
```

The post_db function is fired by a button like

```
<button onclick="post_db(this)" class="btn btn-success">Conferma</button>
```

On the backend I'm using Django and the view that manages that URL is

```
def fetch_new_seq(request):
    json_ricevuto = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
    print(json_ricevuto)
    messages.success(request, "Ricevuto")
    redirect_url = reverse('newSeq')
    return JsonResponse({'url': redirect_url})
```

For some reason, the fetch is fired two times as I'm seeing the function on the backed with the same results two times

I can't understand why it happens tho as, the button is clicked just one

I'm also seeing on the console of Mozilla Browser I got the error ***Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.***

The button that fires the post_db is inside a certain number of divs

```
 <div id="container" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <h3>Creazione di sequenze di movimento</h3>
    <input
      type="text"
      class="form-control mt-3 mb-3"
      id="titleseq"
      placeholder="Inserisci Titolo"
    />

    <div class="row">
      <div class="d-grid gap-2 col">
        <button onclick="load_js()" class="btn btn-secondary">
          Riordina
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="d-grid gap-2 col">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button onclick="post_db()" class="btn btn-success">
          Conferma
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="d-grid gap-2 col">
        <button onclick="addNewRow()" class="btn btn-primary">
          Aggiungi Movimento
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The issue you're experiencing could be related to event propagation. When the button is clicked, the **post_db** function is triggered. However, if there are any parent elements of the button with click event listeners, they might also receive the click event and trigger the function again.

Comment: Is button inside a <form> tag?

Comment: @pierpy nope, it's just a standard button in the html

Comment: @АлександрОкостень the button has no parent element with click event... please see the updated question for the full html

Comment: Client and server are on the same machine? I mean, no CORS pre-requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I may have found the issue. The `async` function with the `fetch` code was inside a `for` loop like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < len_array; i++) {
  if (
    comandi_json["lista_comandi"][i]["comando"] == "" ||
    comandi_json["lista_comandi"][i]["tempo"] == null
  ) {
    console.log("Error");
    return;
  } else {
    async function postData() {
      const url = "fetchnewseq";

      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(comandi_json),
      });
      return await response.json();
    }
    postData().then((data) => {
      window.location.replace(data.url);
    });
  }
}
```

Clearly, every time the first check was performed correctly without `return`, the `else` got fired and, with it, the `fetch` function triggered it more than once and generated the issue.

Rewriting it outside the for fixed the issue

```
for (var i = 0; i < len_array; i++) {
  if (
    comandi_json["lista_comandi"][i]["comando"] == "" ||
    comandi_json["lista_comandi"][i]["tempo"] == null
  ) {
    console.log("Error");
    return;
  } 
 }

    async function postData() {
      const url = "fetchnewseq";

      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(comandi_json),
      });
      return await response.json();
    }
    postData().then((data) => {
      window.location.replace(data.url);
    });
```